# linux limits.conf not working?

Tags: linux, core-file

I configured /etc/security/limits.conf like this.

```
user1               soft    core            0
user1               hard    core            0
```

Then, I rebooted the system and logged in as root
then I did this.

```
su user1
ulimit -c unlimited
```

then I executed a buggy application to generate core file.
since I set the core limit to zero from limits.conf, I expected the core will not be generated but, that was not the result, the core was normally generated.
what's wrong??

some advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`limits.conf` is read by `pam_limits.so`, so you need to check that this module is enabled in `/etc/pam.d/su`.  On my system, this was commented out by default:

```
# Sets up user limits, please uncomment and read /etc/security/limits.conf
# to enable this functionality.
# (Replaces the use of /etc/limits in old login)
# session    required   pam_limits.so
```

Once uncommented, the module will start working immediately.  If you still have problems, check your auth log (maybe `/var/log/auth.log`), which is where limits-related errors will be written.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this as well

```
# echo DefaultLimitNOFILE=65535 >> /etc/systemd/system.conf
# echo DefaultLimitNOFILE=65535 >> /etc/systemd/user.conf
```